# Display selected node of treeview control in textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am beginner to .net and i want to put selected node string to a textbox. May be it is not possible to do with treeview control because it has no use in application.

ps I tried to insert choices in listcheckbox control on a button click, may be this thing is also not possible.

Do you have another way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TreeView control has an event called `AfterSelect`.
You can use this event to detect when an item has been selected.

Here's a sample code:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    extBox1.Text = e.Node.Text
End Sub
```

Of course, you will need to change `TreeView1` and `TextBox1` for the actual names of your treeview and textbox controls.

---

To add items to a `CheckedListBox` when a button is clicked, you would use a code similar to this one:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

This code will add a new item to `CheckedListBox1`, using the text from  the `TextBox1` control as input, when `Button1` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BeforeSelect or AfterSelect event to put a selected node's text into a textbox.

```
textbox1.text = e.node.text
```

Use `checkedlistbox1.items.add()` to add an item to a checkedlistbox.